# How to make a function that take one parameter and boolean in Python

Tags: python, clock

How to make a function hours that receives seconds from 00:00 (midnight) and a boolean parameter that is True to return a 24h-based hour, and False for a 12h-based hour, and returns hours (as a 12h or 24h clock depending on the second parameter)

`def hours(seconds : int, type : bool) -> int: return  seconds // 3600`

Comment: Please don't just post your assignment, actually have a go rather than using StackOverflow as a code-writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just return `(seconds // 3600) % 12` if the type is for 12h, otherwise just return `(seconds // 3600)`?

```py
def hours(seconds: int, type: bool) -> int:
    hours = seconds // 3600
    if type: 
        return hours
    return hours % 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is worded kind of strangely, but this maybe useful for you?

```
def hours(seconds):
    if seconds > 1259:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

`seconds` is parameter to enter for function. Function will return `False` boolean value if entered argument is higher than 1259

Comment: That`s helps, thanks.
i am new in Python and trying to make a code for 7-segment lamp that receives a seconds and return it as list on, off like [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], so i have to defined the houes and minutes and then i am stuck